# saving picture after 5 seconds when a linklabel clicked

Tags: c#, .net

it is little bit hard to solve.. :D first you should solve my english :D :D
i want save a webbrowser snapshot like a this placement
//first : user clicks a linklabel
//
after : program navigates my browser
//
last : 5 seconds later program will takes snapshot of webbrowser.
i have this code for this.but..

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(linkLabel1.Text);

    ///how can i set after 5 seconds take snapshot
    ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).PageScreenshot.Save("thumb1.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

sorry for bad english :( i cannot explain more detailed.
edit:
i will try explain more detailed...
here is my new tab function of my web browser and i want take favorites screenshot.after when user open new tab ,user will see favorites with small photo...
so, if favorite doesnt have any pic,it will be first time.when user click to the link.it will navigates to favorite and then when document completed,it will take screenshot..thats all
[image: new tab]

Comment: Probably you want to take a screenshot when the document has loaded (and you think 5 seconds will be enough). You should use the DocumentCompleted event for this ;).

Comment: yeah but i have more than one link i have 6 link how can i detect which one is clicked?? in document completed event

Comment: i must use event in event it is almost impossible, or not??

Comment: Those events are normally fired automatically, when they occur. On your first question, I realy do suggest you to look into the API of the WebKitBrowser.

Comment: if (((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Url.ToString() == linkLabel1.Text)
            {

                ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).PageScreenshot.Save("thumb1.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            }
            else
            {

            }

Comment: i tried to use that but url isn't starts with everytime http://  or www. ! :(( or ends with / like a facebook.com/ "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can comprehend from your post and comments, is that you have six [`LinkLabel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.aspx)s (named `linkLabel1` to `linkLabel6`). When the user clicks any of the links, your [`WebKitBrowser`](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) control has to navigate to the URL (which is the text of the linklabel) and when the document is loaded, it has to take automatically a screenshot.

Now, as you would like to do all the same with the different linklabels, you should only create one event handler to handle the clicks of the different linklabels. You can just attach the _LinkClicked() event to any of the linklabels. You'll also have to define in your class some private field that will contain the LinkLabel that was last clicked on.

```
private LinkLabel _lastClickedLinkLabel = null;

private void linkLabelX_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    // Cast the sender to a LinkLabel object as you want to know which LinkLabel
    // was clicked on
    var senderLinkLabel = sender as LinkLabel;
    if (senderLinkLabel != null)
    {
        ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(senderLinkLabel.Text);
        _lastClickedLinkLabel = senderLinkLabel;
    }
}
```

Now as you want to take the screenshot after the page is loaded, you'll have to create the [`DocumentCompleted`](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/docs/html/E_WebKit_WebKitBrowser_DocumentCompleted.htm) event. (Don't forget to attach it to your tabControl!)

```
private void tabControl1_DocumentCompleted(Object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Save the screenshot
    // you might want to determine the filename dynamically, otherwise the file will be overwritten
    ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).PageScreenshot.Save("thumb1.png", ImageFormat.Png);

    if (_lastClickedLinkLabel != null)
    {
        // Do something here based upon the _lastClickedLinkLabel
    }
}
```

Note that I don't have actual experience with that exact control, I just used a search engine to find all information.

Comment: can you look again i changed and added subject ? :) :)

Answer (score 0):

i did this below and that works i solved my problem but,last thing i cannot change picture while my application is working..
when document completed,,.......

```
  void Form1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (_lastClickedLinkLabel.Text == linkLabel1.Text)
        {
            ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).PageScreenshot.Dispose();
            ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).PageScreenshot.Save("thumb1.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            // Do something here based upon the _lastClickedLinkLabel
        }
        if (_lastClickedLinkLabel.Text == linkLabel2.Text)
        {
            ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).PageScreenshot.Save("thumb2.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            // Do something here based upon the _lastClickedLinkLabel
        }
        if (_lastClickedLinkLabel.Text == linkLabel3.Text)
        {
            ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).PageScreenshot.Save("thumb3.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            // Do something here based upon the _lastClickedLinkLabel
        }
        if (_lastClickedLinkLabel.Text == linkLabel4.Text)
        {
            ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).PageScreenshot.Save("thumb4.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            // Do something here based upon the _lastClickedLinkLabel
        }
        if (_lastClickedLinkLabel.Text == linkLabel5.Text)
        {
            ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).PageScreenshot.Save("thumb5.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            // Do something here based upon the _lastClickedLinkLabel
        }
        if (_lastClickedLinkLabel.Text == linkLabel6.Text)
        {
            ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).PageScreenshot.Save("thumb6.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            // Do something here based upon the _lastClickedLinkLabel
        }

    }
```

and when links clicked,,.....

```
private LinkLabel _lastClickedLinkLabel = null;

        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            var senderLinkLabel = sender as LinkLabel;           
            if (senderLinkLabel != null)
            {
                ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(senderLinkLabel.Text);
                _lastClickedLinkLabel = senderLinkLabel;

            }




        }

        private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            var senderLinkLabel = sender as LinkLabel;
            if (senderLinkLabel != null)
            {
                ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(senderLinkLabel.Text);
                _lastClickedLinkLabel = senderLinkLabel;

            }
        }

        private void linkLabel3_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            var senderLinkLabel = sender as LinkLabel;
            if (senderLinkLabel != null)
            {
                ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(senderLinkLabel.Text);
                _lastClickedLinkLabel = senderLinkLabel;

            }
        }

        private void linkLabel4_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            var senderLinkLabel = sender as LinkLabel;
            if (senderLinkLabel != null)
            {
                ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(senderLinkLabel.Text);
                _lastClickedLinkLabel = senderLinkLabel;

            }
        }

        private void linkLabel5_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            var senderLinkLabel = sender as LinkLabel;
            if (senderLinkLabel != null)
            {
                ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(senderLinkLabel.Text);
                _lastClickedLinkLabel = senderLinkLabel;

            }
        }

        private void linkLabel6_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            var senderLinkLabel = sender as LinkLabel;
            if (senderLinkLabel != null)
            {
                ((WebKitBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).Navigate(senderLinkLabel.Text);
                _lastClickedLinkLabel = senderLinkLabel;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Avoid copy pasting code, you have six times the same event handler!!! You can assign the same event handler to multiple controls. And again, in your first code, don't copy paste the same if statement 6 times, determine the "dynamic" part and leave the same things just at one place. Read into the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Comment: Please clarify, "cannot change picture". Do you want a different file name for each saved picture? Then you'll have to create dynamically a unique picture name.

Comment: Also, your initial question is answered and it works, as you pointed out. If you are struggling with something else, you should open a new question (but first, TRY YOURSELF, really; you learn a lot more trying many many things to get it to work).